# Page doesn't load in Safari. Activity Window listing instances of about:blank

Tags: safari, rendering

I have a page that doesn't always render in Safari.  It shows up as a blank page.  If I look in the Activity Window, I will see a couple of instances of **about:blank** in the list of resources being loaded.

Simply refreshing the page fixes the problem.

This can be replicated very reliably, and only affects Safari.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Turned out the problem was a control on the page that generated Javascript to create cross-site cookies between two related sites on this project.  Safari is very strict in its rejection of attempts to create cross-site cookies, and it appears this is the resulting behaviour.

As soon as I removed the control, the page rendered consistently in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, also occurs with Google Chrome. Maybe a Webkit related issue? Viewing the page source reveals that the source is properly loaded, but in my case the content div doesn't get rendered. When I try to inspect elements, the div shows up. Error console shows nothing. I'm trying to come up with a fix for this and I'll report back if I succeed.

**EDIT: Solved!**

Is your page dynamically generated? I found out that both Chrome and Safari may fail to render a page correctly if the Content-Length header is sent but its value is incorrect. I didn't send the header explicitly, but we're using a WordPress backend with a custom frontend and included wp-blog-header.php which sent the headers. I switched that to wp-load.php to prevent the unnecessary headers from being sent.

In addition to that, both browsers have a limit on how much data they need to receive before they start rendering. The threshold for Safari seems to be around 1 KB and around 2 KB for Chrome. My pages were longer than that, but I suspect that caching was the reason that the problem persisted at this point.

I tried flushing at the end of the page, but the problem was only completely solved when I started using userspace output buffering (and decided to use automatic compression while I was at it). Now my pages are of the form:

```
<?php ob_start('ob_gzhandler'); ?>
<!-- Static and dynamically generated content -->
<?php ob_end_flush(); flush(); ?>
```

And voilà, after cleaning Safari's cache I got rid of the rendering problems!

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Good things to know about how Safari handles its rendering.